# open and close a form using the same keypress vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have form1 that whenever I press F1..

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    If keyData = Keys.F1 Then
        Form2.Show()
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)

End Function
```

form2 shows..
what I wanted is when form2 is up, and I press F1 again, it closes.
any idea? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the same code you wrote but in Form2 and say form2.close()

```
If keyData = Keys.F1 Then
    Form2.Close()
    Return True
End If
```

Comment: lol didn't even think about it. how about even if I am still pointing at Form1? something like I accidentally hit the mouse on form1. then that code will not work.